# setTimout() is not called when App is minimized and Android phone is locked for a longer period

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, oauth-2.0, settimeout

I'm currently working on a React Native application which uses a timeout to refresh the idToken for authentication. For that, the app uses setTimeout with the timeout set to `EXPIRATION_DATE - 5min` so that the token gets refreshed five minutes before it expires.

I have tried the timeout with smaller durations (~ 5 minutes) and there it always works even when the app is minimized and/or the phone is locked. The behavior then is, that the callback on the timeout is called as soon as the app is opened. But somehow when the timeout is set to a higher value, and the app isn't opened for some time, the timeout function isn't called at all, which obviously results in broken calls because the token never gets refreshed.

I wasn't able to find much about this behavior, so I wanted to double check if this is how setTimeout works with react native (maybe because of some deep sleep of the system or something like that).

Would it be better, if I'd just check that the token is still valid before every call? Because that seems like a overhead for me.

Comment: I used an interceptor to handle that, so let's say that the authentication token is expired and it's throwing an error, it will call another endpoint to refresh the token.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Your solution is actually quite a lot simpler and cleaner.. Thanks a lot! Still wondering how setTimeout works in the described scenario though.. in case I need it in the future